# Is there a way to assign values to a combobox without using a datasource?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework to throw together a combobox with values from my MSSQL database using the following

```
using (var context = new Entity())
{
    var things = (from p in context.Stuff 
                  where ((p.SourceId == StuffId && p.Domain.Value == "Stuff") 
                    || (p.SourceId == OtherStuffId && p.Domain.Value == "OtherStuff")) 
                    && p.Done == true orderby p.StuffId 
                  select p);

    foreach(var stuff in things)
        cboRejectTask.Items.Add(stuff.StuffId + ": " + stuff.StuffType.Description + " " + stuff.StuffType.DisplayName);
}
```

I'd like to assign values to each row so that when it comes time to grab what the user selected I don't have to do string manipulation to get what I want. I don't want to use a datasource if possible.

**Solution**:

Given there isn't a better way to do this than creating a custom class I went ahead and did so using the selected answer's code modified a bit for long-term use. (note: you could really use any given object as long as ToString() returned the "display text" and it had a Tag or any writeable property compatible with your needs)

```
public class ComboBoxItem
{
    public string Display;
    public object Value;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Display;
    }
}
```

Given this code I can now change my code to the following:

```
using (var context = new Entity())
{
    var things = (from p in context.Stuff 
                  where ((p.SourceId == StuffId && p.Domain.Value == "Stuff") 
                    || (p.SourceId == OtherStuffId && p.Domain.Value == "OtherStuff")) 
                    && p.Done == true orderby p.StuffId 
                  select p);

    foreach(var stuff in things)
        cboRejectTask.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem() { Display = stuff.StuffId + ": " + stuff.StuffType.Description + " " + stuff.StuffType.DisplayName, Value = stuff.StuffId });
}
```

Comment: Some controls have a `.Tag` property that could be useful. But since each individual item isn't a control, I'm not sure that's work. You could directly add the object to `Items` and use the `DisplayMember` property to pick what you show (`ValueMember` property may also be useful).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var cbi1 = new ComboBoxItem("Item 1") { Id = 1 };
        var cbi2 = new ComboBoxItem("Item 2") { Id = 2 };
        var cbi3 = new ComboBoxItem("Item 3") { Id = 3 };
        comboBox1.Items.Add(cbi1);
        comboBox1.Items.Add(cbi2);
        comboBox1.Items.Add(cbi3);
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var id = ((ComboBoxItem)comboBox1.SelectedItem).Id;

        MessageBox.Show(id.ToString());

    }
}

public class ComboBoxItem
{
    private readonly string text;

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ComboBoxItem(string text)
    {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return text;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is indeed a solution (and a full one at that, thank you), this'll be the route I take if nothing easier comes along.

Quite a shame though that this isn't easier...it seems like such a simple (and frequent) thing.

Comment: No description at all? I do think that if you provide some description on how your answer addresses the problem, OP and other with similar problems would learn from it, it would be much more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might find this usefull:

```
comboBox1.Items.Add(1);
comboBox1.Items.Add(2);
comboBox1.Items.Add(3);

private void comboBox1_Format(object sender, ListControlConvertEventArgs e)
{
    //this will set what gets displayed in the combobox, but does not change the value.
    e.Value = "display value";
}

private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show((sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem.ToString());
}
```

Comment: I'm aware of adding items (it's in my code after all), I was more thinking of values http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2006/11/07/combobox-selecteditem-selectedvalue-selectedwhat.aspx I probably should've been more specific in that regard...

Comment: you would have to convert the data into an array and use `AddRange()`

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand how that would provide custom values for each item?...Unless you mean referencing the selectedindex of the combobox and then using the same index to reference the array (I've thought of this but the array would need to be global and it'd be quite nasty I'd imagine)

Comment: maybe this could help